# Trying to embed IPython, but stdin == None

Tags: python, ipython, stdin, blender

I'm trying to embed ipython into blender. Blender is packaged with its own python, so to get access to all of my own libraries I copy the list from my ipython3 sys.path variable and do:

```
import sys
for p in 
    sys.path.append(p)

import IPython
IPython embed
```

I get the following error:

```
>>> import IPython
>>> IPython.embed()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<blender_console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/frontend/terminal/embed.py", line 282, in embed
    _embedded_shell = InteractiveShellEmbed(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/frontend/terminal/embed.py", line 97, in __init__
    display_banner=display_banner
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/frontend/terminal/interactiveshell.py", line 360, in __init__
user_module=user_module, custom_exceptions=custom_exceptions
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 455, in __init__
    self.init_readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 1844, in init_readline
    self.refill_readline_hist()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 1853, in refill_readline_hist
    stdin_encoding = sys.stdin.encoding or "utf-8"
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encoding'
```

Any ideas how I can get it to work?

Comment: Did you ever have any progress with this?

Comment: The problem is that sys.stdin is set to None as the blender python console currently does not support stdin input. To solve this we need to create a link into the keyboard input event of blender, and create a bridge that fullfills whatever api that ipython requires of stdin and that connects to blender's input event.

Comment: @DovGrobgeld and did you find a solution?

Comment: Never found a solution. Would've been nice!